# Is it possible to expand $\arctan x \ln(1-x^2)$ in series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, harmonic-numbers

I am not sure if its possible to find the Taylor series of $\arctan x \ln(1-x^2)$ so I am giving it a try:

By using the Cauchy product

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n x^n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_{n-k+1}\right)x^{n+1}$$

we have

$$\arctan x \ln(1-x^2)=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}\right)\left(-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{n}\right)$$

$$=\frac1x\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \underbrace{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n-1}}_{a_n}(x^2)^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}}_{b_n}(x^2)^n\right)$$

$$=\frac1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n-k+1}\right)(x^2)^{n+1}$$

$$\left\{\text{write $\frac{1}{(2k-1)(n-k+1)}=\frac{1}{2n+1}\left(\frac{2}{2k-1}+\frac{1}{n-k+1}\right)$}\right\}$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\right)x^{2n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{n-k+1}\right)x^{2n+1}$$

$$\left\{\text{reverse the order of the terms in the second sum}\right\}$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\right)x^{2n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\right)x^{2n+1}$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{2n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\right)x^{2n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}\overline{H}_n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}.$$

---

Mathematica gives

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}=\int_0^1\frac{(-x^2)^n-1}{1+x^2}dx=-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{(-1)^n}{4}\left(\psi\left(\frac{2n+3}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{2n+1}{4}\right)\right)$$

but this form makes the problem harder I guess. Any idea how to find a better form for $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^n}{2k-1}$ or how to find the whole $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{2n+1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\right)x^{2n+1}$ or maybe a different way to find the Taylor series of $\arctan x \ln(1-x^2)$?

Comment: I think that your $f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} x^{2 m + 1} \frac{1}{
 2 m + 1} ((-1)^{m} (\overline{H}_m + \Phi(-1,1,m+1/2)) - \pi/2)$ where $\phi$ is the Lerch transcendent, is a perfectly acceptable series expansion which can hardly be simplified.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze thanks Wolf. Yes Mathematica gave me such form as well but I wanted get something different as I am not well familiar with $\phi$ function  plus its not common to use I guess.

Comment: @ Ali Shadhar, pls see my solution which is just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my results for the coefficients of the Taylor expansion. A possible derivation is shown in §5.

**$1 solution in terms of harmonic numbers**

Let

$$f(x):=\text{arctan(x)}\log(1-x^2) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_n x^{2n+3}\tag{1}$$

then the coefficients, expressend completely through harmonic numbers, are

$$\begin{align}c_H(n) = \frac{1}{2 (2 n+3)} \left(-\pi + H_{\frac{n}{2}}-H_{\frac{n+1}{2}}\\
+(-1)^{n+1} \left(H_{\frac{2n+1}{4}}-H_{\frac{2n-1}{4}}+\log (4)\right)\right)\end{align}\tag{2} $$

It is useful to write down the expressions for even and odd $n$ separately

$$\begin{align}
c_{H}(n_{even})=&\frac{1}{2 (2 n+3)}\left( H_{\frac{n}{2}}+\left(H_{\frac{1}{4} (2 n-1)}-H_{\frac{1}{4} (2 n+1)}-\pi \right)\\-\left(H_{\frac{n+1}{2}}+\log (4)\right)\right)
\end{align}\tag{2a}$$

$$\begin{align}c_{H}(n_{odd})=\frac{1}{2 (2 n+3)}\left(-H_{\frac{n+1}{2}}+\left(-H_{\frac{1}{4} (2 n-1)}+H_{\frac{1}{4} (2 n+1)}-\pi \right)\\+\left(H_{\frac{n}{2}}+\log (4)\right)\right)\end{align}\tag{2b}$$

Notice that the non-rational numbers $\log(4)$ and $\pi$ combine with harmonic numbers with half-integer and quarter-integer indices, resp. leaving rational expressions for $c_{H}(n)$. Specifically, in $(2b)$ and $(2b)$ the brackets in the numerator are rational numbers.

You can see this from the following relations (here $n$ is a non negative integer)

$$H_x = H_ {x - 1} + \frac {1} {x}$$
$$H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k-\frac{1}{2}}+H_{-\frac{1}{2}}\text{ and } H_{-\frac{1}{2}}=-\log (4)$$
$$H_{n\pm \frac{1}{4}}=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k\pm \frac{1}{4}}+H_{\pm \frac{1}{4}}$$
$$H_{-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\pi }{2}-\log (8)\text{ and }H_{\frac{1}{4}}=-\frac{\pi }{2}+4-\log (8)$$

The results in $(2)$ were obtained from §2 in two steps

(1) write digamma functions in terms of harmonic numbers using

$$\psi(x) \to H_{x-1} - \gamma$$

(2) transform arguments of $H_x$ in the negative range  to positive values using the reflexion formula

$$H_{1-\alpha }=\frac{1}{1-\alpha }-\frac{1}{\alpha }+\pi  \cot (\pi  \alpha )+H_{\alpha }$$

My reviously obtained equivalent results are:

**§2. solution containing limits of digamma functions**

Playing around with double integral representations I came up with the following form of the coefficients

$$\begin{align}c_n=\lim_{k\to n} \,\left( \frac{1}{2 (2 k+3)}\left((-1)^{k+1} \left(\pi  (-1)^k+2 \pi  (-1)^k \csc (\pi  k)-2 \pi  \sec (\pi  k)\\
-(-1)^k \psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{k}{2}\right)+(-1)^k \psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{k}{2}\right)\\
+\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\log (4)\right)\right)\right)\end{align}\tag{3}$$

Despite the horrible expression the values of $c(n)$ are rational for $n=0, 1, 2...$.

The simplicity of the formula lies in the fact that it needs only digamma functions.

**§3. solution with the limits in §2 carried out**

Here is the result with the limit carried out in two equivalent forms:

$$\begin{align} c(n_\text{odd}) = \frac{1}{2(2n+3)}\left(\pi + (-1)^n \left(H_{\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor +1}-\gamma -\log (4)\right)+\left(-\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n-1)\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n+1)\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n)\right)\right)\right)\end{align} \tag{4a}$$

$$\begin{align}c(n_\text{odd}) = \frac{1}{2(2n+3)}\left(\pi + (-1)^n \left(H_{\frac{n+1}{2}}-\gamma -\log (4)\right)+\left(-\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n-1)\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n+1)\right)+\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n)\right)\right)\right)\end{align} \tag{4b}$$

$$\begin{align}c(n_\text{even}) =\frac{1}{2(2n+3)}\left(\pi+(-1)^n \left(H_{\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor +1}-\gamma -\log (4)\right)+\left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n-1)\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n+1)\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n+2)\right)\right) \right)\end{align}\tag{5a}$$

$$\begin{align}c(n_\text{even}) =\frac{1}{2(2n+3)}\left(\pi+(-1)^n \left(H_ {\frac{n}{2}}-\gamma -\log (4)\right)+\left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n-1)\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n+1)\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{4} (2 n+2)\right)\right) \right)\end{align}\tag{5b}$$

**§4 Recursion**

The difficulties with the recursion of the coefficients encountered in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4474186/198592 can easily be overcome when we consider the coefficients multiplied by $2(3+2n)$

$$d_e(n) = 2(3+2n) c(n_\text{even})\tag{6a}$$
$$d_o(n) = 2(3+2n) c(n_\text{odd})\tag{6b}$$

From $(2a,2 b)$ we find easily ($n$ is even here)

$$d_e(n) - d_e(n-2) =\left( -\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{4}{2 n-1}-\frac{4}{2 n+1}+\frac{2}{n}\right)\tag{7a}$$
$$d_o(n+1)-d_0(n-1) = \left(-\frac{2}{n+2}-\frac{4}{2 n+1}+\frac{4}{2 n+3}+\frac{2}{n+1}\right)\tag{7b}$$

The initial conditions are

$$d_e(0) = -6, d_o(1) = -\frac{5}{3}$$

These linear recursion relations are easily solved by Mathematica. The resulting expressions come in terms of the Lerch transcendent. They are, of course, equvalent to our solutions (because we have derived the recursion relations from them).

Having calculated $d(n)$ we have simply to invert $(6)$ to find the coefficients themselves.

**§5 Derivation of coefficients using integral representations**

We write the two factors of $f(x)$ as follows

$$\tan ^{-1}(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{s^2 x^2+1} \, ds\tag{5.1}$$
$$-\log \left(1-x^2\right)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{1-t x^2} \, dt\tag{5.2}$$

$f(x)$ is then given by the double integral

$$f(x) = -x^3 \int _0^1\int _0^1 \frac{1}{\left(s^2 x^2+1\right) \left(1-t x^2\right)}dtds\tag{5.3}$$

Decomposing the fraction

$$\frac{\frac{s^2}{s^2 x^2+1}-\frac{t}{t x^2-1}}{s^2+t}$$

and expanding into geometric series gives the coefficient $a(k)$ of $x^{3+2k}$ as the double integral

$$\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{(-1)^k s^{2 k+2}+ t^{k+1}}{s^2+t}dsdt\tag{5.4}$$

To do the integrals we can successfully employ Mathematica.

The t-integral gives

$$i_t =\int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^k s^{2 k+2}+t^{k+1}}{s^2+t} \, dt=\frac{\, _2F_1\left(1,k+2;k+3;-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)+(-1)^k (k+2) s^{2 k+4} \log \left(\frac{1}{s^2}+1\right)}{(k+2) s^2}\tag{5.5}$$

here $_2F_1\left(a,b;c;z\right)$ is the hypergeometric function.

The subsequent s-integral gives

$$\begin{align}a(k) = & \int_0^1 i_t \, ds\\
& =\frac{(-1)^{k+1} \Phi \left(-1,1,k+\frac{5}{2}\right)}{2 k+3}+\frac{2 (-1)^k}{(2 k+3)^2}\\
& +\frac{\pi }{4 k+6}+\frac{(-1)^k \log (2)}{2 k+3}\\
&+\frac{\psi\left(\frac{k+3}{2}\right)}{4 k+6}-\frac{\psi\left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right)}{4 k+6}\end{align}\tag{5.6}$$

Here $\Phi \left(z,s,a\right)$ is the Lerch transcendent and $\psi$ is the digamma function.

The first few values are

$$a(k)_{k=1}^{k=6} = \left\{1,\frac{1}{6},\frac{11}{30},\frac{121}{1260},\frac{281}{1260},\frac{929}{13860}\right\}$$

We see that $a(k) = c(k)$.

Comment: Thank you Wolf.. interesting result (+1)

Comment: @Ali Shadhar Thank you, Ali. See my new version of the solution which you might like since it conatains only harmonic numbers.

Comment: Thanks Wolf... much nicer

Comment: Wolf in (5a), did you mean $c(n_\text{odd})$?

Comment: The odd case in $(5a)$ would look much nicer if we let $n=2q+1$

Comment: Ali, no, (5a) is correct. It differs from (4a) in the sign of the digamma functions.
Ali, "... look much nicer" yes, therefore the "nice" formulas are collected in §1.  .

Answer (score 1):

*A bit tricky but it makes things simpler.*

Rewrite
$$\tan ^{-1}(x)\log \left(1-x^2\right) = x \frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x}\log \left(1-x^2\right)$$ and let $x=\sqrt t$
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}(\sqrt t)}{\sqrt t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{2 n+1}t^n$$
$$\log \left(1-t\right)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {t^n} n$$

Where is see a problem is that the coefficients of the product
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}(\sqrt t)}{\sqrt t}\,\log \left(1-t\right)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,t^n$$ being
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{6},\frac{11}{30},\frac{121}{1260},\frac{281}{1260},\frac{929}{1
   3860},\frac{432683}{2702700},\frac{18527}{360360},\frac{84971}{680680},\frac{203
   75981}{488864376},\cdots\right\}$$ nothing has been identified by $OEIS$.

Comment: Thanks Claude for trying

Comment: @AliShadhar. I had no hope from the start. Looking at a problem which involves harmonic numbers, if **you** say that you are stuck, then ..... Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\arctan(x)\ln(1-x^2)$

Multiplying the series of $\arctan$ and $\ln$ with the Cauchy product reveals a bit difficult, but we can separate the two series by derivation. This works because the derivatives of these two functions involve polynomials.

$f'(x)=\dfrac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}-\dfrac{2x\arctan(x)}{1-x^2}$

After multiplication by the same common denominator we get the formula:

$$(1-x^4)f'(x)=(1-x^2)\ln(1-x^2)-2x(1+x^2)\arctan(x)$$

Expanding the series gives:

$\begin{align}LHS
&=(1-x^4)\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n+3}\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n-\sum\limits_{n=4}^\infty (n-3)a_{n-3}x^n\\
&=a_1+(2a_2)x+(3a_3)x^2+(4a_4)x^3+\sum\limits_{n=4}^\infty \Big((n+1)a_{n+1}-(n-3)a_{n-3}\Big)x^n
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}RHS
&=(1-x^2)\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)}{n}x^{2n}-(2x+2x^3)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}\\
&=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n}x^{2n}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n}x^{2n+2}-2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+2}-2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+4}\\
&=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n}x^{2n}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n-1}x^{2n}+2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}x^{2n}-2\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n-3}x^{2n}\\
&=(-1-2)x^2+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \Big(-\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n-1}+2\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}-2\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n-3}\Big)x^{2n}\\
&=-3x^2+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \Big(\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}+\dfrac{(-4)(-1)^n}{(2n-1)(2n-3)}\Big)x^{2n}
\end{align}$

We can now proceed to identify the coefficients of the two sides of the equation to find an induction relation between the $a_n$ terms.

$\begin{cases}
a_1=0\\
a_2=0\\
a_3=-1\\
a_4=0\\
\forall n\ge 2 & a_{2n}=0\\
\forall n\ge 2 & (2n+1)a_{2n+1} = (2n-3)a_{2n-3} + \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}+\dfrac{(-4)(-1)^n}{(2n-1)(2n-3)}\\
\end{cases}$

Also from $f(0)=0$ we have $a_0=0$

Calculated iteratively we can verify that we obtain the same coefficients than Claude:

$$-x^3-\frac{1}{6}x^5-\frac{11}{30}x^7-\frac{121}{1260}x^9-\frac{281}{1260}x^{11}-\frac{929}{13860}x^{13}-\frac{432683}{2702700}x^{15}+O(x^{17})$$

Finding a closed formula seems rather intractable as it is an induction relation with non-constant coefficients, but for practical purposes, you can easily calculate all the $a_n$ up to a given order using this step by step relation.

Comment: thank you for your efforts.. much appreciated (+1).

Comment: @zwim "Finding a closed formula seems rather intractable" but nevertheless there is a closed form of the coefficients (in terms of digamma functions) which is given here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4474269/198592